# .Net core scaffold dbcontext fails with Could not load type 'System.IO.File'

Tags: c#, macos, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I created a classlib library in .Net core 2 (preview 1).
Then I added packages for Entity framework.
Now I would like to scaffold a database:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "azure connection string" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

But I receive this error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.IO.File' from assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>          
> at System.Diagnostics.StackTraceSymbols.GetPdbPathFromPeStream(String assemblyPath, IntPtr loadedPeAddress, Int32 loadedPeSize, Int32& age, Guid& guid, UInt32& stamp)
>         
>  at System.Diagnostics.StackTraceSymbols.GetReader(String assemblyPath, IntPtr loadedPeAddress, Int32 loadedPeSize, IntPtr inMemoryPdbAddress, Int32 inMemoryPdbSize)
>          
> at System.Diagnostics.StackTraceSymbols.GetSourceLineInfo(String assemblyPath, IntPtr loadedPeAddress, Int32 loadedPeSize, IntPtr inMemoryPdbAddress, Int32 inMemoryPdbSize, Int32 methodToken, Int32 ilOffset, String& sourceFile, Int32& sourceLine, Int32& sourceColumn)
>          
> at System.Diagnostics.StackFrameHelper.InitializeSourceInfo(Int32 iSkip, Boolean fNeedFileInfo, Exception exception)
>          
> at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.CaptureStackTrace(Int32 iSkip, Boolean fNeedFileInfo, Thread targetThread, Exception e)
>          
> at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
>          
> at System.Exception.GetStackTrace(Boolean needFileInfo)
>          
> at System.Exception.ToString(Boolean needFileLineInfo, Boolean needMessage)
>          
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)

This is the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Do I need to add an extra package? Is this a bug?

**Answer:**

The answer of Alaa Masoud is correct, but here is some more information.
I did a 'dotnet add package EntityFramework', but I needed the EF Core and also the preview version since I'm using the .Net core preview.
These were the correct commands:

```
dotnet add package -v 2.0.0-preview2-final Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
dotnet add package -v 2.0.0-preview2-final Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
dotnet add package -v 2.0.0-preview2-final Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet
```

I also changed the project type from 'netstandard2.0' to 'netcoreapp2.0'. The scaffolding only seems to work with a runnable project.
Here is my new project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing EF 6.1 as well as EFCore 1.1.2. Remove `<PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.1.3" />` from project.json and change the version of EFCore to `2.0.0-preview2-final` since you're targeting .net standard 2.0.

Comment: I am trying to get a net461  ef6 project to run on .net Core 2 . I asked the question here (at the bottom): https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/271 . Shouldn't it be possible run ef6  under net Core via the netstandard compatibility shim ?

Comment: How does one even create a shim mapping  for an existing library ?